# Filter list of colors in numpy like image in opencv

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am filtering colors in opencv like so:

```
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

    lower_blue = np.array([60, 25, 120]) 
    upper_blue = np.array([180, 255, 255]) 

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue) 

    out = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
```

can I do something similar to a list of colors (not an image)?

Like a PIL color list

```
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open('test_64col.png')
    im.getcolors(w*h)
```

you get a list of colors like so:

[(256000, (244, 61, 0)), (178240, (0, 176, 176)), (77760, (133, 133, 0))]

Which contains the pixelcount, and the R,G,B values.

I need a lot of filter masks and would like to use the same np.array filter mask that I use for the opencv image filtering if possible.

Comment: do you mean that you want to filter colors list using upper/lower RGB or HSV ranges? if not, please clarify your expected result.

Comment: I dont know how to do the numpy filtering. I do know how to convert the RGB values to HSV but for keeping it simpler we can keep it with RGB values. So how do I define a filter with 3 values(RGB or HSV)  ( upper lower) on an np.array or a list of colors? I do have to use the lower + upper like in the opencv example above.

Comment: I wonder if I can convert the list of colors in an image with 1 pixel height and len of the list length an then use opencv again ? would this be possible ?